# On which site can I ask a question about the available linker flags for Xcode?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I would like to ask if someone has compiled a list of other linker flags for Xcode. On which Stack Exchange site is this question appropriate?

Comment: Stack Exchange sites **are not forums**.

Comment: If there's no where to ask a question about how to use Stack Overflow, there needs to be. Getting marked down because I'm trying to use the site respectfully makes no sense.

Comment: The FAQ is the place to start. It is linked to on _every_ page. I don't know who downvoted this question, but it was probably downvoted as it is not a very clear question (and some people are touchy about SE sites being called forums).

Comment: This is the kind of stuff that people usually look for (and find) in **documentation**. Try Google.

Comment: (Please compare the current title with the original one. See the difference? The original title was surely worth a downvote, in my opinion.)

Comment: Id'd start with Google :):):)

Comment: It would be easier to type "man ld" and more rewarding.

Answer (score 2):

This is a question about an IDE/linker which makes it appropriate to Stack Overflow, though you may want to phrase it as a proper question, something to the tune of:

> What are some undocumented linker flags for Xcode? I am aware that they exist, as detailed in ....

Comment: Also, you may want to phrase it in such a way that it doesn't turn into a list question like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/146297/hidden-features-of-xcode , because those types of questions aren't a good fit for the Stack Exchange format and tend to be closed pretty quickly now.

Comment: What happened to [general reference questions not being welcome](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/02/are-some-questions-too-simple/)? I very much agree with The Establishment's comment to the question: there's no fit on any Stack Exchange site, I'd say.

Comment: I disagree. If the OP has a concrete question, ("Is there a linker feature that does X, I can't find one.") then it's a good question. Stamp-collecting so-called undocumented options is just shopping.